# JQuery loop through outer div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="container">
    <div rownumber="0" messageid="155" class="post" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
        <div class="post_body"><span>asdfjhasf as dfkhgfk  dsfad fbd lfgldfgl dsgflag flugad luf gaduf ad fuilad lifg adslf gluad fluad fluiadlufg asu fglasd gfl</span></div>
        <div class="post_info"><ul><li class="vote" id="voteli">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the container `div` has only one child at the moment, but say it had like 10 or something, the number is arbitrary. How would I loop through the container `div` in JQuery and for each child, call a JQuery plugin on the `div class="post_body"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
$("#container > div").each(function () {
    $("div.post_body", this).pluginMethod();
});
```

Comment: This would work, but you don't need the child selector or the manual iteration over the elements. You're causing the dom traversal to happen multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery object returned from a selector is an array of matching elements.

Since you know what your outer container is, and you know you want to perform an operation on all elements of that class, you know your selector.

```
$('#container .post_body').each(function(a,b) { });
```

Also, plugins are usually written to iterate over this array.  So you should be able to do:

```
$('#container .post_body').plugin();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container > .post > .post_body').pluginMethod();
```